# Problem Installing SharePoint 2013 SP1

Tags: 2013, service-pack

I'm trying to install SP1 on my SharePoint 2013. But when I run the .exe I got error while detection.

Do you have any ideas ?

I checked the OPatchInstall log, but I can't find anything because it's too huge.

Edit: Server is W2008R2. Only 1 server with SharePoint 2013 and SQL Server. Current version is  : 15.0.4420.1017 (RTM). And I'm trying to install the kb2880552.

When I try to install March2013PU and October2013CU or directly SP1, I still got the same error "error occured while running detection process". I tried foundation updates and server updates, no luck.

When I use PowerShell to detect which product is installed, I got this two IDs : 
9ff54ebc-8c12-47d7-854f-3865d4be8118
b7d84c2b-0754-49e4-b7be-7ee321dce0a9

These IDs refer to "Foundation 2013" and "Server 2013".

Comment: what is the error you get.

Comment: "Error while detection process" just after I accept the licence and press next

Comment: What version are you running on right now? RTM? How many servers in the farm?

Comment: is your win server 2008 R2 with SP1. and are you installing an update SP1 for your already installed Sharepoint 2013

Comment: yes 2008R2 SP1, sp2013 already installed (edit question)

Comment: Are you running SharePoint foundation or server? Might be that you have the wrong service pack.

Comment: When I check (I did not install this myself) I can see both installed ... so I guess server should be good ... I checked with a powershell script that I found on the internet

Comment: kb2880552 is for Sharepoint Server  and for SharePoint foundation it is kb2880551 .... please check on this

Comment: If you are running SharePoint server, this is the correct package. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42544 if it does not work, you might find something in the sharepoint logs.

Comment: I did see this, but do you know a real way to be sure if server or foundation is installed ?

Comment: Check if on your server March 2013 PU and October CU are missing. This might be one of the cause of the detection error

Comment: March 2013 PU is not needed for SP1. :)

Comment: Can you confirm I can check this from CentralAdministration in upgrade status ?

Comment: you can check what SharePoint is installed from the central administration in the following way. If you check CA >> manage Service applications , there are many services does not exists in SharePoint Foundation like Search , Access , Web analytics,.. It is definitely Sharepoint Server installed when you have these services installed

Comment: I got "access services"

Comment: Installing the october update requires to restart service and server ?

Comment: According to this post http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2013/10/26/october-2013-cu-for-sharepoint-2013-has-been-released.aspx I need March 2013 PU to install October 2013 CU then SP1. Can you confirm ?

Answer (score 0):

See the article [How To: Detect the Installed SKU of SharePoint 2010 on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff721969.aspx). It has a list of GUIDs for each SKU:

```
BEED1F75-C398-4447-AEF1-E66E1F0DF91E: SharePoint Foundation 2010     
1328E89E-7EC8-4F7E-809E-7E945796E511: Search Server Express 2010       
B2C0B444-3914-4ACB-A0B8-7CF50A8F7AA0: SharePoint Server 2010 Standard    Trial 3FDFBCC8-B3E4-4482-91FA-122C6432805C: SharePoint Server 2010       Standard 88BED06D-8C6B-4E62-AB01-546D6005FE97: SharePoint Server 2010    Enterprise Trial D5595F62-449B-4061-B0B2-0CBAD410BB51: SharePoint       Server 2010 Enterprise BC4C1C97-9013-4033-A0DD-9DC9E6D6C887: Search      Server 2010 Trial 
08460AA2-A176-442C-BDCA-26928704D80B: Search Server    2010 
84902853-59F6-4B20-BC7C-DE4F419FEFAD: Project Server 2010 Trial     
ED21638F-97FF-4A65-AD9B-6889B93065E2: Project Server 2010       
926E4E17-087B-47D1-8BD7-91A394BC6196: Office Web Companions 2010
```

You can look for these within the registry key `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Web Server Extensions\14.0\WSS\InstalledProducts.`

### You can also use the PowerShell command `get-spfarm | select Products` to output GUIDs for the installed SKUs.

For 2013 you can see the information about the SharePoint products installed under System Settings -> Manage servers in the farm

[image]

Comment: When I use PS command, it outputs two IDs : `9ff54ebc-8c12-47d7-854f-3865d4be8118` and `b7d84c2b-0754-49e4-b7be-7ee321dce0a9`. And I'm using SharePoint 2013, while in your answer you provides infos for SP2010. And it seems like both Foundation and Server are installed ... i don't understand

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong during the SharePoint installation. You need to repair SharePoint then extract SP1 again before installing it.

Regards,
-T.s

Comment: Yes, that's possible. I would like to test installing each patche manually. But sadly, I was asked to stop this subject for now ... So I'll comeback later to give feedbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Repairing your SharePoint should definitely will resolve your issue.

You check the following article from [tech-net article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/86dd5dfa-0085-4ce5-b93a-62ac1c0d8c53/an-error-occurred-while-running-detection-cannot-install-exe-files-sp1-or-any-other-kb?forum=sharepointadminprevious).